# Streaming some audio format files on iOS device

Tags: ios, audio, wav, flac, aac+

Just would like to know: is there any iOS native framework/SDK supports the streaming of HE-AAC (AAC+) audio files? And any iOS framework/SDK to stream .wav and FLAC (Free Lossless Audio Codec) audio files? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use AVAudioPlayer.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Chapters/Reference.html

Check the supported formats in Apple docs:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2